# Use curl parameters on bash script where some characters breaks the string

Tags: bash

I can't figure it out.

I have this:

```
id=$(curl -s --data "content=${1}&comment=${dtime}&mode_name=JavaScript" \
        https://paste.merkoba.com/save.php | jq -r '.url')
```

Content can be something like:

```
#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
struct Main<'a>
{
    point: &'a Point,
    letter: char
}
```

Since content has a & character the curl string breaks.

How can I turn content into an escaped string, or how do I format the curl command to work correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `--data` use a `--data-urlencode` for each `var=value` part. curl will encode the value part, and add the intervening `&`.

```
curl \
--data-urlencode "content=${1}" \
--data-urlencode "comment=${dtime}" \
--data-urlencode "mode_name=JavaScript" ...
```

(The same applies for GET by simply adding option `-G`).